# Oracle connection through visual studio

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, ado.net, tnsnames, odp.net

I installed oracle client 11.2.0 version in my machine and also installed Oracle data access providers for visual studio.I also installed Oracle Data Access 11.2.0.3.20. I am trying to connect to the database through the visual studio i am getting the below exception

```
ORA -12504 : TNS: listner was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA**
```

The tnsnames.ora file contains the folloing code

```
creds=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = aaa.cedd.net)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = creds)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just alter `SID` to `SERVICE_NAME`:

```
creds=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = aaa.cedd.net)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = creds)
    )
  )
```

Comment: i changed SID to SERVICE_NAME  but still i am getting the same exception

Comment: Any chance that adding `SERVICE_NAME` will help instead of replacing?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be loading the TNSNAMES.ORA file you think it's loading.  Instead prefer [Easy Connect Naming](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm#i498306).  Here something like '//aaa.cedd.net/creds'